# How to delete elements from array in Angularjs application

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am trying to do a basic task: removing an item from my array. 

The array looks like that:

```
myWordsInJSON = [{"eng":"frau","rus":"жена"},{"eng":"mann","rus":"муж"},{"eng":"witwe","rus":"вдова"},{"eng":"witwer","rus":"вдовец"},{"eng":"schwiegervater","rus":"свекор"}]
```

Here is my html code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in myWordsInJSON">
          <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
          <td>{{item[Params.lang1]}}</td>
          <td>{{item[Params.lang2]}}</td>
          <td><span class="label label-danger"
                         ng-click="cut({{$index}})">x</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
```

[Output screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/Y7cw0iEA9)

It looks great. When I press the 'delete' label, my Controller's cutting function starts:

```
 $scope.cut = function(index){
  $scope.myWordsInJSON.splice(index,1);
  if ($scope.myWordsInJSON.length == 1)
    $scope.myWordsInJSON = [];
  console.log('cuted, index =', index,$scope.myWordsInJSON);
};
```

But than strange things happens.
After cutting a few items from the beginning of my array, I've got this picture:

[everythig looks ok](http://screencast.com/t/RXolQtUarR7)

DOM looks great, last element of my array is:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in myWordsInJSON" class="ng-scope">
          <td class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding">2</td>
          <td class="ng-binding">schwiegervater</td>
          <td class="ng-binding">свекор</td>
          <td><span class="label label-danger" ng-click="cut(1)">x</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
```

BUT!!! When I am pressing on this element, which has to invoke my cut function like **cut(1)**, nothing happens and in my console I see

> index = 4

that means that my function is getting  *index=4* instead of *index=1*

So, it looks like my indexes from initial page compilation is still here...
How can I solve this problem?

***Update!***

The problem solved by using '$index' instead of '{{$index}}'. Sanks to  [valverde93](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3877938/valverde93). But I still cant understand why that happens ))) Maby someone can explane?

Comment: Add `id` field in each object in the array and delete by id.

Comment: Can you add JSfiddle or Plunker ?
I suspect your index is not being decreased

Comment: But I've created [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mt3rnp5q/), replaced `{{$index}}` to `$index` and everything is work fine

Comment: valverde93, thanks a LOT !!! Maby you can explane the difference using $index and {{$index}} in my example? And why cut(1),  sending from my DOM, is not working when cut($index) works great...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've encountered the same issue in my current project. The problem was that the index of the the repeated elements and the actual index of the object in that array are different.


To solve the issue I had to pass the ID of the object like this

`ng-click="deleteForId(repeatedElement.id)` 

and then, in the `deleteForId` function, I search for that object in the array and get its index. Only then I call

`$scope.myObj.splice(index, 1);`